# Django form field issue with model formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm having an issue with rendering individual form fields in a template.  I have a model formset that I'm re-ordering after creation to make displaying a little easier on the template.  Nothing too complicated, but rendering the form fields isn't working.  You can see in the template where I try and render `{{ form.train }}`, but nothing shows up in the output.  However, the form is definitely there because `{{ form.instance.user.name }}` works correctly.

I opened up PDB and inspected the form variable that I'm adding into the dictionary, and it says `<django.forms.widgets.ScheduleForm object at 0x10c58bc50>`.  I'm not sure if that helps or not, but I wanted to provide as much info as possible.

**The Model Form**

```
class ScheduleForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Schedule
        fields = [
            'train',
            'semi',
            'tri_axle',
            'flow_boy',
            'misc',
            'material',
            'notes'
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
formset_fields = ('train','semi','tri_axle','flow_boy','misc','material','notes')
ScheduleFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.Schedule, fields=formset_fields, extra=0)

formset = ScheduleFormSet(queryset=queryset)

# Getting form in the right format
ordered_forms = {}
for form in formset:
    # Make sure the job exists on the object
    if not form.instance.job.number in ordered_forms:
        ordered_forms[form.instance.job.number] = {}

    # Make sure the user exists on the object
    if not form.instance.user.name in ordered_forms[form.instance.job.number]:
        ordered_forms[form.instance.job.number][form.instance.user.name] = []

    # Append to correct place.
    ordered_forms[form.instance.job.number][form.instance.user.name].append(form)

# Dict will look like
# { 'jobID' : { 'user' : [form1,form2,form3] } }
```

**Template**

```
    {% for job, users in ordered_forms.items %}
        <h2>{{ job }}</h2>
        {% for user, forms in users %}
            <table class='table striped'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ user }}</th>
                        <th>Train</th>
                        <th>Semi</th>
                        <th>Tri-Axle</th>
                        <th>Flow Boy</th>
                        <th>Misc</th>
                        <th>Material</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for form in forms %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form.instance.broker.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form.train }}</td>
                        <td>Semi</td>
                        <td>Tri-Axle</td>
                        <td>Flow Boy</td>
                        <td>Misc</td>
                        <td>Material</td>
                        <td>Notes</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: There are some very weird things going in your code, not least of which is your repeated use of `hasattr` to check if a key exists in a dictionary. That  doesn't do that at all: you mean `key in dict`, eg `if not form.instance.job.number in ordered_forms`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Good point.  No idea what I was thinking there.  Updated that bit of code to suck less.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to add `.items` to `{% for user, forms in users %}`.

```
{% for job, users in ordered_forms.items %}
        <h2>{{ job }}</h2>
        {% for user, forms in users.items %}
            <table class='table striped'>
                ....
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```